# Python defining methods

Tags: python

I have been reading some python code out there and I see some variations on how one write method.

Some write (example 1):

```
def A() :
*method A implementation*

def B():
*method B implementation*
```

Others write (example 2):

```
def A() :
*method A implementation*

   def B():
   *method B implementation*
```

Does anyone know the difference, pro and cons of example 1 versus example 2 ?

Thanks =)

Comment: Question, all local variables from function A will be accessible in function B?

Comment: Do you have the indentation right?  Do you know what indentation means in Python?  If you know what indentation means, what are you asking?

Comment: @arthurprs yes, except when they are shadowed with another variable in `B` with the same name.

Comment: @Giulio Piancastelli like an anonym method then?

Comment: @arthurprs I'm afraid I don't know how an anonymous method would look like in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand in the second example function `B()` will be accessible only from the function `A()`. And in the first one both functions will be globally accessible.